# How to write a simple python program that prints letters in ascending order?

Tags: python, string

For example I would like to have:

a

.
.
.

z

aa

ab

.
.
.

az

bz

.
.
.

zz

aaa

and so on.

Currently I'm here but I am lost. So feel free to propose a completely different solution.

```
count = 0
string = ''
for i in range(100):
    count += 1
    if i % 26 == 0:
        count = 0
        string += 'a'
    ch = 'a'
    x = chr(ord(ch) + count)
    string = string[:-1] + x
    print(i + 1, string)
```

and my output is something like this:

1 a

2 b

.
.
.

26 z

27 za

28 zb

.
.
.

52 zz

53 zza

54 zzb

.
.
.

Comment: please do not remove your attempt from the question (I reverted the edit). It was almost-good question, and after your edit it became close-to-be-closed one. It is important that you show your own efforts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using more of standard library:

```py
import itertools
import string


for i in range(1, 3): # Print items of length 1 and 2
    for prod in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=i):
        print(''.join(prod))
```

What you describe is a sorted output of n-th powers of set `{'a'...'z'}` in terms of cartesian products in string format (cartesian power `n` of a set `X` is, from a simple point of view, a set of all possible tuples `(x_1, ..., x_n)` where all `x_i` are contained in `X`). `itertools.product` implements exactly cartesian product and outputs in order of presence, so just loop over them. `string.ascii_lowercase` is a simple string containing all letters `a..z` in natural order. This is fast (uses C implementation of `itertools`).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try something like the following:

range(97,123) simply creates a range of numbers from 97 to 122, which converted to ASCII equates to a...z (done using chr())

So all our FUnction does, is it recieves a base string (starts with empty), prints out the base + range of charachters and calls its self with base + every charachter as the new base and depth decremented by 1

```
def printcharachters(base, depth):
    if depth > 0:
        for a in range(97, 123):
            print(base + chr(a))

        for a in range(97, 123):
            printcharachters(base + chr(a), depth - 1)



printcharachters("", 2)
```

Replace the depth with your desired depth (for 2 the last string would be zz for 4 it would be zzzz).